# Existence and uniqueness theorems for ODE. Log-Lipschitz regularity.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a linear space with a complete metric $d:\mathbb{X}\times\mathbb{X}\to [0,+\infty)$. Let's $B[x_o,b]$ is a compact ball of radius $b$ centered at $x_o$.

> *THEOREM:If $F:[t_o-a,t_o+a]\times B[x_o,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{X}$ a limited application, continuous and continuous Lipschiz in $B[x_o,b]$ (note that if $\mathbb {X}$ have finite demension the condition is limited to be redundant).Then there exists a unique solution
>   $$
> \varphi : [t_o-\alpha,t_o+\alpha]\to B[x_o,b]
> $$
>   to the problem of Cauchy
>   $$
> x'(t)=F(x,t)\quad x(t_o)=x_o
> $$
>   where $\alpha=\min\{a,b\backslash M\}$ and $M=\sup\{|F(t,x)| : (t,x)\in [t_o-a,t_o+a]\times B[x_o,b] \}$.*

DEFINITION:We say that $F$  is $\gamma$-log-Lipschitz in $B[x_o,b]$ if there exist $\gamma \ge 0$, $L>0$ and $C>0$ such that
$$
\|F(x,t)- F(y,t) \| \le C{\bigg(\log\frac{L}{\|x-y\|}\bigg)^{\gamma}}\|x-y\|,
$$
 for all $ x,y \in B[x_o,b]$ and all $t\in [t_o-a,t_o+a]$.

**QUESTION 1.** There is a version of this theorem for  Log-Lipschitz fields?We may waive the conditions of compactness of the ball and the range in this case?

**QUESTION 2.** There are other more unusual versions of this theorem where the field $ F $ satisfas
 $$
\|F(x,t)- F(y,t) \| \le |\Psi(x,y)|\cdot\|x-y\|,
$$
 for some function $ \Psi :\mathbb{X}\times\mathbb{X}\to\mathbb{R}$?We may waive the conditions of compactness of the ball and the range in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition for a modulus of continuity $h(t)$ to give uniqueness in ODEs is that the integral of $dt/h(t)$ is divergent at $0$ (exercice). Hence for your log-lipschitz modulus, you have uniqueness iff $\gamma\leq 1$. The corresponding flow is then Hölder, with exponentially decreasing exponent.

Comment: A regularity more general than shown in Question 2 above proposed by the @user25917. For every $ t $ the application $ F (\;,t) $ has continidade module $ h $ is $$ \| F(x,t)-F(y,t) \| \leq h (\|x-y\|)\quad \forall x,y\in\mathbb{X} $$ For more see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity

Comment: @user25917 What did you mean by "the integrale of $dt/h(t)$ is divergent at $0$. I don't know how you will you do to prove it. Any hint is welcome.